# About identically distributed random variables

Tags: probability

I am reading a paper and wanted to check if the following random variables are identically distributed.

Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ be iid and $X_j\sim \mu$ for all $j\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$ where $\mu$ is some distribution. Let $Z=f(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_j,\cdots, X_n)$ and $Z_j=f(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_j',\cdots,X_n)$ where $X_j'\perp \!\!\! \perp X_j, X_j'\sim \mu$ and

\begin{align}
f(x_1,\cdots,x_n) &= P(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i) \\
f_j(x_1,\cdots,x_n) &= P(\sum_{i\neq j} X_i=\sum_{i\neq j} x_i) 
\end{align}

> It is given in the paper that $Z-f_j(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ and $Z_j-f_j(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ are identically distributed because $X_j'$ is an independent copy of $X_j$ and $f_j$ does not depend on the $j^{th}$ variable.

Q1) Is it true that $Z$ and $Z_j$ are identically distributed?

Q2) If the above is true, then $Z-f_j$ and $Z_j-f_j$ are also identically distributed. So may I know where we use the fact that $f_j$ does not depend on the $j^{th}$ variable?

Comment: If $f(x_1,\dots,x_n):=P\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)$ then it seems to me that: $$f(X_1,\dots,X_n)=P\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)=1$$ Similarly $f_j(X_1,\dots,X_n)=1$. Is that really intended?

Comment: @drhab We are looking at different instances of $X_1,\cdots,X_n$. So $f(X_1(w),\cdots,X_n(w))=P(\eta \in \Omega | \sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\eta)=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(w))$ where $\Omega$ is the underlying probability space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's false as you state it. Instead of the condition $X'_j\perp X_j$, you need that $X'_j\perp(X_i, i\ne j)$, so that $X_1, X_2, \dots, X'_j, \dots, X_n$ is also an i.i.d. collection.

Under that condition, the vectors
$(X_1, \dots, X_j, \dots, X_n)$ and
$(X_1, \dots, X'_j, \dots, X_n)$
have the same distribution. So if $g$ is any function, then
$W:=g(X_1, \dots, X_j, \dots, X_n)$ and $W':=g(X_1, \dots, X'_j, \dots, X_n)$ have the same distribution.

Now if you've got some further thing that "does not depend on the $j$th variable", say $Y=h(X_1, \dots, X_{j-1}, X_{j+1}, \dots, X_n)$, then
$W-Y$ and $W'-Y$ have the same distribution. This is just another application of the previous paragraph, since $W-Y$ is a function of $X_1,\dots,X_j,\dots, X_n$
and $W'-Y$ is "the same function" of $X_1,\dots, X'_j,\dots, X_n$.

However, if you had a second quantity that *did* depend on the $j$th coordinate, say
$Z=r(X_1, \dots, X_j, \dots, X_n)$, then you couldn't conclude that $W-Z$ and $W'-Z$ have the same distribution. In that case $W'-Z$ would be a function of all $n+1$ variables
$X_1,\dots,X_j, X'_j, \dots, X_n$.

Comment: $X_j'\perp X_j$ means that $X_j' \perp X_i$ for all $i$ because $X_j\perp X_i$ for all $i\neq j$. So indeed $X_1,\cdots,X_j',\cdots,X_n$ is an iid collection. So I guess as you stated in second paragraph, indeed $Z$ and $Z_j$ are identically distributed?

Comment: Just because $U\perp V$ and $V \perp W$, it does not follow that $U \perp W$!! Just check the case where you define $W=U$, for example. (Assuming that "$U\perp V$" is meaning "$U$ and $V$ are independent", right?)

Comment: I see, that's true.

Comment: May I know why $(X_1,\cdots,X_j,\cdots,X_n)$ and $(X_1,\cdots,X_j',\cdots,X_n)$ have the same distribution when $X_1,\cdots,X_j,\cdots,X_n$ and $X_1,\cdots,X_j',\cdots,X_n$ are iid collections?

Comment: If you know a vector is i.i.d., and you know the common distribution of its entries, then, well, you know everything there is to know about its distribution! That's a complete description of the distribution. Say for example $(X_1, X_2)$ and $(Y_1, Y_2)$ are both i.i.d. with the same common distribution $\mu$. Then for any $A$, $B$, you have $P(X_1\in A, X_2\in B)=P(X_1\in A)P(X_2\in B)=\mu(A)\mu(B)$ $=P(Y_1\in A)P(Y_2\in B)=P(Y_1\in A, Y_2\in B)$. So $(X_1, X_2)$ and $(Y_1, Y_2)$ have the same distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Can we look at it this way?

$Z$ depends on the $j^{th}$ variable, because:
$$
\begin{align}
Z=f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)&=P(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)\\
&=f_j(x_1,\cdots,x_n)P(X_j=x_j)+(1-f_j(x_1,\cdots,x_n))P(X_j=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i-\sum_{i\neq j} X_i)
\end{align}
$$

We can then compare with the similar expression for $Z_j$ to see that they are identically distributed.

If $f_j$ depended on $X_j$, then
$$
Z=f_j(x_1,\cdots,x_n\vert_{X_j=x_j})P(X_j=x_j)+P(X_j=??)\dots
$$
I don't know what follows.  And we couldn't claim that $Z$ and $Z_j$ are identically distributed anymore.